# Pandas: Define type of new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal is that `event_id` is not saved as `float`, but as `int`.

```
list_of_event_ids = orders["event_id"].unique().tolist()
print(list_of_event_ids)
```

The output here is `[180, 181]`

```
data_for_csv = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ds", "yhat", "yhat_lower", "yhat_upper"])

for event_id in list_of_event_ids:
    [...]
    forecast = m.predict(future)
    # Here I add event_id to the forecast DataFrame
    forecast["event_id"] = event_id
    new_row_for_data_for_csv = forecast[["event_id", "ds", "yhat", "yhat_lower", "yhat_upper"]].tail(1)

    data_for_csv = data_for_csv.append(new_row_for_data_for_csv, ignore_index=True)

print(data_for_csv)
```

The output here is:

```py
     ds                                   yhat        yhat_lower  yhat_upper
0    2019-10-03 04:36:09.982632  180.0    5.826519    3.382635    8.365737
1    2019-10-04 06:28:09.699094  181.0    5.212132    3.529156    12.831940
```

Can you explain to me why the list `[180, 181]` is converted to `float`? How to avoid that behavior?

Comment: Hello, have you tried `forecast["event_id"] = pd.to_numeric(forecast["event_id"], downcast='integer')` ?

Comment: you can convert the type back to integer with `df['event_id'] = df.event_id.astype('int64')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert it as an `int` just do this:

```
data_for_csv.event_id = data_for_csv.event_id.astype('int64')
```

I chose the 64 bits representation but you can adapt it to 8, 16, 32, ...

If you have missing values it won't work because NaN are float and cannot be converted to Integers.

If you want to convert to integer a column with missing values, Pandas realeased a way of doing it:

```
data_for_csv.event_id = data_for_csv.event_id.astype('Int64')
```

Notice the difference with the capital "I".

> Documentation here:
>
> [Series.astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html)
>
> [Nullable integer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you use DataFrame.append to add the data, the dtypes are preserved from where your are appending data.

you can avoid that behavior by assigning the dtypes to columns explicitly. e.g.

```
data_for_csv.event_id=data_for_csv.event_id.astype(int)
```